# How to select first of the month from date field without TRUNC?

Tags: oracle, date, truncate

Is there a way to select the first of the month from a date field without using the trunc function? It is slowing my query down way too much. I have it in the where clause like this:

```
WHERE trunc(DATE_FIELD, 'MM') = :v_Month
```

The query runs in 4 seconds without the trunc function but returns an incomplete dataset. With the trunc function all the data will be returned, but the query will take over 20 minutes to run.

DATE_FIELD has many days in a month but I just need to first of the month for each record. So if DATE_FIELD =  14/09/2016, I need to somehow get 01/09/2016 but not using trunc.

Is this possible?

**UPDATE:**

Removed to_date() from code. That was a mistake being in there and is not used in the actual full query.

Comment: Beware of [asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps you can provide more details about what slows down your query, like showing the explain plans of both queries.

Comment: Please post full query and replace `:v_Month` with a value. There is probably another way of optimizing it...

Comment: You are using `to_date()` on DATE_FIELD. This makes sense only if DATE_FIELD is a string field (varchar2 or similar), not a date field. If so, there is little you can do; you are paying the price for storing dates in the wrong data type. If in fact DATE_FIELD is a date data type, use the solutions in the Answers provided.

Answer (score 5):

There are other ways to get the first of the month for a date.  But those approaches won't be any more efficient.  Almost certainly, the root of your issue is that there is an index on `date_field`.  When you use `date_field` without any function call on it, Oracle can use that index and your query is efficient.  As soon as you put any function call around `date_field`, however, Oracle can no longer use that index so you're stuck with a much less efficient query plan.  The issue is not that `trunc` is slow, the issue is that putting any function call on an indexed column prevents the use of that index.

Given that, you have two alternatives

1. Create a function-based index on `trunc(date_field, 'MM')` and leave the query unchanged.
2. Reformulate the query so that you have conditions on `date_field` without a function

Something like

```
where date_field >= :v_Month
  and date_field <  add_months(:v_Month,1)
```

Comment: @mathguy - The original question was "how do I truncate without using `trunc`" with the explanation that `trunc` was too slow.  I'm saying that there are other ways of truncating a date but they won't fix the performance problem because the performance problem is not that `trunc` is slow but that it prevents the query from using an index.

Comment: Sorry, I already removed my comment since I realized the same.

Comment: At the same time I noticed what I put in my Comment to the original question. If DATE_FIELD is a date, then wrapping it within `to_date` already causes problems and slow execution, regardless of anything else. And if it's a string field none of these solutions will work, alas.